# Creating an Arithmetic Function without input

Tags: function, math

i got this task from my teacher to create an arithmetic function without using input and i dont really know how to do it, i been trying to fix it but i couldn't, can anyone please help me?

The task was this

"You should create a program that calculates the nth number and sum of languages ​​in an arbitrary arithmetic series. The user must choose the values ​​of The first number in the number sequence, different between two on each other according to numbers in the series and how many numbers the series must contain."

Comment: What did you try? Do you already have a solution with using input? What programming language are you using? By "sum of languages", do you mean "sum of terms"? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) might be of some help.

Comment: Is this a really mathematics question? "What is the formula for the nth number in an arithmetic sequence?" "What is the formula for the sum of an arithmetic sequence?" Those formulas are [well-known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html).

Comment: Everything i've tried hasn't worked, and the formula for a arithmetic sequence is N=A1+(N-1)*d.  "A1" is the first number in that list and "N" is how many numbers there are in the arithmetic table and "d" is the difference between these numbers.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you have tried so far, and explain more clearly what "doesn't work" means. (Doesn't compile? Doesn't run? Runs but produces the wrong result? What result do you get and what did you expect?)